# Illustrator: How to achieve this look?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Got quick question - been strugling with that for a while. I'm expanding my skills with illustrator and trying to achieve various effects. Right now I try to copy that effect - filling object with continiously upscaled stroke.

[image: how_he_did_that]

Author:https://instagram.com/swainland/

So i started with two simple shapes (red one) and then scaled them down. After that used pathfinder. I got two shapes with strokes scaled down. And that's when problems started:

1. My shape seems to be a little bit clumsy. In original picture shape is well rounded, without visible curving. In my copy place when stroke curve ends and straight line starts is very well visible.
2. It seems that in original picture white/blue and pink/yellow strokes all ends in one place. On my shape it's just upscaled stroke cut in half with pathfinder, so naturaly they end on pink outline.

I assume that 1 problem is all about setting the right value on handles. But second one - I have no clue. Is it blurring ?

[image]

Comment: To be honest - not much. I know this is possible just by drawing shapes, but I don't think thats the point. 

I started with drawing two shapes - inner rounded rectangle and outer rounded rectangle just to have outline of whole shape. After that i draw the first, light blue circle and scaled it down. And that is where problems started - scaling just won't make it look good.

Comment: Well, if you haven't really tried. Asking someone here to try harder than you have and then explain on top of that is a bit much to ask if you aren't even willing to put forth some effort. Don't you think?

Comment: Well, fair enough - I did not make myself clear enough. I updated post with work I did so far. Main problem:

In original artwork Author somehow made all the inside strokes of bigger and smaller shape to end at one point - how ? I assume all postproduction was made in PS, but shape must have been done in AI. When i use scale tool i just make shapes bigger.

Comment: I don't think the original has a fill. Rather, it's a blending the two pill shapes.

Answer (score 9):

It's just a case of adding Blend to your shapes:

Start off by creating the base shapes like so

[image]

The add a blend between shape 1 and 2 in the image above and you'll be left with thise (after adjusting the steps)

Object > Blend > Make >

Object > Blend > Blend Options

You'll be left with something like this

[image]

Then repeat the same steps between shape one and two in this pic

You should then be left with an image that looks like this

[image]

[image]

All you need to do then is apply the colour to your first and last shape so it blends between them. and repeat for the inner blend and you're done!

That's it for the main effect, anything else will be post effects like noise for the grainy look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Blend" from "Object" menu and build the shapes between outer and inner path.
This is how you can do it:

1. Draw the outer and inner shapes and choose their colors
2. Select both objects
3. Go to Object/Blend and click on Make
4. Again go to Object/Blend and this time select Blend options
5. In the dialog set "spacing" on "specified steps"
6. Set the number on something like 20
7. Select OK
8. Now you must have what you wanted